# JS. Есть ли событие, которое зажигается, когда input становится disabled

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно перехватить момент, когда `input` (в моём случае это `checkbox`) становится `disabled` и запустить некоторую логику. Есть ли такое событие? А если нет, то как можно это сделать подругому?

Comment: Если оно внезапно становится disabled — значит его меняет какой-то js-код. Если его меняет какой-то js-код — то значит вы просто можете написать всю нужную вам логику в том же самом js-коде рядом с тем местом, которое меняет disabled. Зачем здесь событие?

Comment: @andreymal Я использую Vue и свойство disabled у меня привязано к вычисляемому свойству, поэтому значение disabled меняется. Я конечно мог бы написать логику в самом вычисляемом свойстве, но во-первых - это костыль, во вторых - на это ругается ESLint

Comment: Значит, наверное, логику стоит менять в том месте, которое приводит к изменению значения вычисляемого свойства? Пока что со стороны выглядит будто вы хотите накостылять что-то странное

Comment: @andreymal К изменению значения вычисляемого свойства приводит vuelidate. В моём вычисляемом свойстве я смотрю, если существуют ошибки валидации, то я запрещаю менять чекбокс.

Comment: @andreymal Когда ошибок в форме нет, я могу поставить его в checked. Но если же значение чекбокса - checked, то когда в форме снова появляется ошибка, мне нужно снова сделать чекбокс неотмеченным.

Comment: Тогда просто напишите watch-функцию с нужной логикой внутри? `watch: {'$v.someField.$invalid': (invalid) => console.log(invalid ? 'Невалидно' : 'Ура, валидно!')}`

Comment: Написать функцию `setInterval`, которая каждую минуту будет проверять `checkbox` на наличие `disabled`? ;)

Comment: @andreymal Оу, спасибо большое. Даже не подумал об этом. Написал и теперь всё работает)

Comment: @Pilaton Можно конечно, но боюсь, что начальник на кол посадит

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input) хоть и на jQuery, но максимально подробно разложили

Comment: @veselllov Видел, но в этом вопросе обсуждают обработку клика по disabled, мне же нужно было перехватить момент, когда инпут становится disabled. Но мне тут уже подсказали, что делать)